# How to fix `Encountered <EOF> at line 1 ...` issues

Tags: java, database, derby

I'm trying to make a derby database in JavaFx project and this error appears to me when I run the project and table is created but I cannot add a row to the table.

Here is the code:

```
void setupMEMBERTable() 
{
    String TABLE_NAME = "MEMBER";
    try {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        DatabaseMetaData dbm = conn.getMetaData();
        ResultSet tables = dbm.getTables(null, null, TABLE_NAME.toUpperCase(), null);
        if (tables.next()) {
            System.out.println("Table" + TABLE_NAME);
        } else {
            stmt.execute("create TABLE MEMBER("
                    +"full_name varchar  (200),"
                    +"address  varchar  (200),"
                    +"mobile  varchar  (200),"
                    +"email varchar(200) primary key ,"
                    +"password  varchar  (200),"
                    +"status boolean default true " + ")"); // Updated
        }
    } catch (SQLException e){
        System.err.println(e.getMessage()+"........SETUP DATABASE");
    } finally { }
}

public ResultSet execQuery(String query) {
    ResultSet result;
    try {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        result = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception at execQuery:dataHandler" + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        return null;
    }
    finally {
    }
    return result;
}

public boolean execAction(String qu) {
    try {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.execute(qu);
        return true;
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error:" + ex.getMessage(), "Error Occurred", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        System.out.println("Exception at execAction:DataHandler " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        return false;
    }
    finally {
    }
}
```

Error

```
   Exception at execAction:dataHandler23505 : [0] SQL0000000001-03d30059-0177-5922-d5b6-00001e28fd60, [1] MEMBER
```

It happens when I try to add a new Member. As you see the query is not executed in `execAction(qu)` method.
What can I do to solve the problem?

Comment: unrelated to javafx, please remove the tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like you are missing a `)` in the line:

```
"status boolean default true <HERE>");
```

I believe that the `Encountered <EOF> at line 1` Exception message is a Syntax Error issued by the database driver, as it is still expecting stuff when it gets to the end of your statement, in your case 177 characters long.

Comment: Yeah, I fixed this and the syntax error is gone but it gives this error                           Exception at execAction:dataHandler23505 : [0] SQL0000000001-03d30059-0177-5922-d5b6-00001e28fd60, [1] MEMBER                                                                                  when I try to add any row to the database , could you help me with that?

Comment: I'm a bit confused here, have you changed your question? Now my reply makes no sense as it relates to a different question!

Comment: However on doing a bit of googling I came across something that suggests that error code 23505, means 'Violation because of duplicated key'. See https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.1/ref/rrefexcept71493.html

Comment: your first answer was right and fixed the previous error, but when I run the code this error showed so I changed the question . thank you so much for helping

Comment: It's my first time to create a database so Can I sent you the database Handler code to tell me what is wrong with it? because I have been trying to fix multiple errors for over 10 days now.

Comment: So, it seems the error (the latest one) is being thrown from the `stmt.execute(qu);` statement in your method `execAction`, if I'm following correctly? So assuming your talking about the table created in the `setupMEMBERTable` method, it looks like you are adding more than one record with the same `email` field as that is the `PRIMARY KEY` and therefore needs to be unique - hence the 23505 (or Violation because of duplicated key) Exception thrown.

Comment: P.S. can you change the title of the question back to the original, so that my answer makes sense, This is supposed to be a resource for others as well as fixing your issue!

Comment: P.P.S just for your info, I have no idea about JavaFx (I don't think this is your problem) Looks like the issue is with the database. Also not really sure about your initiial statement 'I'm trying to make a derby database' . I'm just doing the debug is that not your job?

Comment: I have changed the title to relate to my answer, Hope that's OK

Comment: Thank you again. and yes, the problem is in database not in JavaFX but its a JavaFX Project. And I'm a Computer Science student in year 2. I almost know nothing about database I'm learning and this first trial for OOP Project for college .

Comment: So to help you more, in your catch block, you may find helpful to either use:
`ex.printStackTrace()` or  
use a proper logging framework (like Slf4j),  then you can use stuff like:  
`log.error("Exception is ..:", ex);`  
This will give you more informative error information.

Comment: so for Slf4j see:
http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html
otherwise, if you are using Lombok you can just prepend the class definition with `@Slf4j`, which gives you access to the `log` Object and makes things much easier ... look into it :-)

Comment: By the way you can not do 'just anything' with databases, when you create the tables, constraints are put in place (for example the primary key you set on the MEMBER table), these mean that if you try to do something that will violate that constraint the database driver will throw an error.